# Saxon transformation

Tags: xslt, soap, saxon

I have this stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                xmlns:tes="http://testwork/">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/*"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and this xml file

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tes="http://testwork/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tes:sayHelloWorldFrom>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg0>?</arg0>
      </tes:sayHelloWorldFrom>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want to get a body from this xml with this xsl, I use Saxon for the transformation, here it is my piece of code

```
public void get(String xml, String xsl) throws ServiceException {
TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xsl));           
transformer.transform(new StreamSource(xml), new StreamResult(System.out));
```

but during the execution of the method I have an error

> javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Failed to
>   compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.
>           at net.sf.saxon.PreparedStylesheet.prepare(PreparedStylesheet.java:220)
>           at net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:132)
>           at net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:87)
>           at service.ResponseService.getRequestSoapBody(ResponseService.java:76)

So what is wrong?

Comment: I have tested your code, running Saxon 9.5 HE from the command line, and it does not give an error. Which version exactly do you use? The only odd thing in your code is `version="1.0"` for an XSLT 2.0 processor but that should only give a warning, not an error.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that's wrong is that you are not displaying the compiler error messages. Saxon by default sends the messages to System.err, but if you're within an application with a graphical user interface, there's a fair chance you never see what's written there. So redirect the messages somewhere else. You could use System.setErr() to direct it to a file, or to a window in your GUI application; there are also controls at the Saxon level to send the output of different compilations to different destinations.

There's nothing wrong with the code that you've shown us.

I suspect (but this is only a guess) that your variable "xsl" contains the stylesheet code as a string, whereas it should contain the URI of the location of the stylesheet.